# Association Class Confusion

Tags: associations, uml, class-diagram, ooad

In the class diagram a User can take multiple exams. An Exam is made up of several categories. Each Category has many questions. Each Question has many choices.

The two places I have questions about are where the User interacts with the Exam.

A friend of mine said I should have an association class between User and Exam called Examination. I guess, as attributes, it could have DateTime and Score. Why can't Exam store the score and have a completion date?  (Doesn't that mean that when the exam is complete it simply changes states?) With this design i guess it will have to have an attribute for User as well. This will couple User and Exam.  (If i need Examination to store the score, then will I need a CompletedCategory to store the individual scores for each Category?)

The other place is the relationship between User and Question. Or should it be User and Choice? I need somewhere to store the response to the questions before the score is calculated.  These responses have to be saved to the Database as well. Should Response be an association class or a list in Question?

Can someone explain to me the pros and cons? Is there a good resource I can read? I've read lots of StackOverflow articles. I learned a lot but still not sure which are the best designs.

The following article was helpful: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9900/Identifying-Object-Oriented-Classes

But I'm still not sure why this is true: "For example, a Student class has an association to a Course class. A student can take many courses, and a course can be taken by many students. However, who is responsible for the grade? **Placing the grade in the Student class gives a student the same grade for all courses. Placing the grade in the Course class gives all students taking the same course the same grade.**"

Why can't each Exam, in my case, not simply have a User assigned to it. True that does seem to imply an Exam Session or Examination as my friend said. I can't justify it by clear explanation. Then what do i do with Category which has it own scores and Responses?

Thanks!

[image: Association Example1]

[image: Association Example2]

Comment: Do all M:N relationships have to have an association class like junction tables are needed in relational databases? I don't see why a user can't select an exam from a list, and then on the Exam Screen it displays the over all score and the scores for each category. The score was originally 0 or NULL now its has a value. Why not?

Answer (score 3):

The `Examination` class would relate the `Student` and the `Exam`. The `Student` is an entity and lives (hopefully) on its own. The `Exam` is also an individual entity (it's all the questions and answers that relate to each other). Now the `Examination` comes in and relates both. Since a `Student` can have many `Exams` and vice versa you need something to couple both.

Now whether you take a simple class or an association class is (as I see it) more a matter of taste. You would use a simple association like 
[image]
if you just combine two objects and add some attributes (like `score` and `completionDate`).

The use of an association class
[image]
should be used if you add also operations which enhance the association between `Student` and `Exam` (e.g. to deliver a set of students the have a specific grade).

However, I'd say that both notations are interchangeable.

Regarding the question/answer I'd simply add a question/answer class and make an exam composed of them:

[image]

Though this is quite simplistic but from here I would start to go into details.

Comment: Thanks for replying to my question. I'm aware of the association and how and why association classes are formed. I'm not sure WHY I need an association class. What happens if I DON"T use an association class. I'm trying to explore the justification for having one. I hope you follow me. The text in bold above was an attempt to explain what would happen without an association class BUT it did not go into detail satisfactory so I can examine the PROs and CONs. Thanks!

Comment: I have tried to address exactly this issue. If that doesn't make it clear, I can't help.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it more thought.

Comment: @gwag Ah yes. Thanks for pointing me to the mult. issue. I'll correct that. Regarding "taste": Both representations are exchangeable if you have the `A 1-* C *-1 B` relation. The assoc.-class notation is just a shortcut for this.

Comment: Notice the revised model in my answer, which is now using an association class. I also explain that the model variant where `Participation` (or `Examination` in your model) is a plain class, need to have an additional constraint for preventing duplicate participations/examinations, which are prevented in the association class variant because association ends are unique by default. Consequently, your two variants are only exchangable, if you add this constraint to your first model.

Comment: @gwag Good explanation - got my vote. What you and others don't know: the OP was after implementation differences of ACs rather than missing semantic issues behind the concept (got that from a LinkedIn discussion). Anyway: good answer :-)

Answer (score 3):

The model below includes all your entity types (except categories). Notice that while a test (as an instance of `Test`) is an ***event type***, a test execution (as an instance of `TestExecution`) is a specific ***event*** (with occurrence time). It's a general modeling pattern that events have participations by objects, such as the participation of a person in a test execution. Such a participation is also an event.

Since participations can as well be viewed as links (relationships) between events and their participants, we may model an association `Participation`.

In the case of test participations, we want to record the grade achieved by the participant. For this purpose, the UML concept of an *association class* comes in handy. It allows to define attributes (and other class features) for an association, with a visual notation that clearly indicates its nature as an association, as shown in the following class diagram:

[image: Model of Multiple Choice Tests]

Notice that since association ends are unique by default, this model implies that the same person can have at most one participation link with a particular test execution, which is a constraint that holds for participations in test executions, indeed. If we wouldn't model `Participation` as an association class, but rather as a class, as in the following model, we have to express this constraint explicitly:

[image]

### Further explanations

As requested, here are some additional explanations about the basic categories of information modeling: *entities*, subsuming *objects* and *events*, and *entity types*.

In Ontology, which is the philosophical study of what there is, the following fundamental distinctions are made:

1. there are entities (also called individuals) and entity types (called ‘universals’ in philosophy);
2. there are three fundamental categories of entities:

   1. objects (called ‘endurants’ in philosophy),
   2. tropes, which are existentially dependent entities (such as qualities, dispositions and material relationships), and
   3. events (called ‘perdurants’ in philosophy).

These ontological distinctions are discussed, e.g., in ([Guizzardi and Guarino 2015](http://www.inf.ufes.br/~gguizzardi/CAISE2015-CR.pdf)) and in ([Guizzardi et al. 2013](http://www.inf.ufes.br/~gguizzardi/Towards%20Ontological%20Foundations%20for%20the%20Conceptual%20modeling%20of%20events.pdf)).

Clearly, objects and events are the most basic categories for modeling information systems and information management apps.

UML links (understood as material relationships) are based on events. For instance, an is-married-to link between two persons is based on their marriage (or wedding) event. The fact that links are based on events implies that associations (as link types) are based on event types, and there is a certain ambiguity whether to model certain concepts as an event type or as an association.

Objects participate in events. Events are ontologically dependent entities in the sense that they existentially depend on their participants in order to exist. Take for instance the event of Caesar being stabbed by Brutus. In this event we have the participation of Caesar himself, of Brutus and of the dagger.

There is an interesting, and fundamental, duality between objects and events: while all temporal properties of objects are defined in terms of the events they participate in, all spatial properties of events are defined in terms of the spatial properties of their participants.

After modeling all relevant object types in the first step, we model the relevant event types in a second step. The main type of association between events and objects is participation. When adding event types to the object types in our (conceptual) information model, we therefore also model the participation types between them.

Comment: "It's a general modeling pattern that events have participations by objects, such as the participation of a person in a test (execution)." This is very interesting and insightful.  Can you provide me with more information on this pattern. Also information or article on how to identify events would be good too. Events are still a big foggy for me. Thanks!

Comment: I like the design. Again it is quite insightful. Can you explain the role of Participation a little more. For example, what does it mean that TestExecution can have many participations? Or for a person to participate many times?  Thanks again.

Comment: I've aded further explanations and links to my answer. A TestExecution is a specific test/exam on a certain date, and since there are many persons taking the test, there are many participation events, each linked to a specific test and to a specific person. A person may have many participations, but each one in a different test.

Comment: After learning about the UML2 semantics of association classes, I now think that they are useful and have changed my model and added some explanations about the use of association classes. I hope this also helps you to overcome your association class confusion.

Answer (score 1):

> Why can't Exam store the score and have a completion date?

You are right. "The Exam on Math/Algebra 2nd semester" COULD have several examinations, if we take exam as finishing the course and examination as a try for the finishing. But here, as you have put questions in the Exam, the date and time belong to it, too. Your exam IS the examination already.

Without any doubt, your model can be greatly improved by dividing your huge classes into smaller and more convenient ones. But your model can work, too.

Comment: "But here, as you have put questions in the Exam, the date and time belong to it, too. Your exam IS the examination already."  Can you explain this further? I've thought this but I'm not exactly clear. I"m wondering if just coding will the design will make all this more clearer. Right now its perhaps too abstract for a newbie like me. Although I'm not sure its exactly like an examination in that it does have a name and it can be taken numerous times while an examination is an instance in time. (I think)

Comment: "Without any doubt, your model can be greatly improved by dividing your huge classes into smaller and more convenient ones. But your model can work, too." What smaller classes might you break this up into? I modeled this from my Use Case Diagrams and Sequence Diagrams. I do see how gwag was able to see and pull out more classes, but his knowledge is due to knowledge of a pattern I don't currently know.  Thanks again

Comment: @JacobPressures I think the gwag model could be a decent start. The only errors I see there is that TestExecution and Participation are really 1:1 and I don't see the need to separate them. And the second one - you has categories in your source model, and they are not here.... No pattern is used, except the principle "analyze and separate". But as I have said, your model is a working one. Try to code it and after that make a pair of improving changes - you will see the need to divide large classes into small ones.